# WatchKit call webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, watchkit

I'm currently working on a Apple Watch app and I'm facing a problem.
Since the app company I'm working on doesn't have a API, and is not planning to make, I use a UIWebView to parse some HTML into the app.

I'm trying to port this to the Apple Watch, but I cannot open a UIWebView in background using the handleWatchKitExtensionRequest delegate.

Is there any way to run a UIWebView background task and send some data from it to the Apple Watch app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any method to run a UIWebView in the background. I think you'll have to use something like [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) to download your HTML. Hopefully, you can reuse your parsing logic as-is.